# md5 hash using hashFunction c#

Tags: c#, md5

I have this code:

```
...
   private void bBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string FileName = ofd.FileName;
                tbKeyFile.Text = FileName;
            }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbKeyFile.Text))
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(tbKeyFile.Text, FileMode.Open);

            MD5 hashFunction = MD5.Create();
            byte[] computedHashCode = hashFunction.ComputeHash(fs);

            string HashInString = Convert.ToBase64String(computedHashCode);

            lHash.Text = HashInString;
         }

    }
...
```

But it's not calculating a md5 hash. It's calculating a SHA1 checksum. 
What do I do wrong ?

Comment: That sounds unlikely.  How are you checking the output?

Comment: `MD5.Create().ComputeHash()` certainly won't return a SHA1 hash.

Comment: It's computing an MD5 hash with Base64 encoded output. Were you expecting hex encoded output? `BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-","")` can be used to obtain a hex encoded hash.

Comment: Please post an example consisting of: 1) input 2) expected output 3) actual output.

Comment: Input: 213441dasses
Output: M1UOF9zlCe+LwCfDNcWGPw==
Expected output: 33550e17dce509ef8bc027c335c5863f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [CodesInChaos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445517/codesinchaos) said: [`MD5.ComputeHash()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s02tk69a.aspx) returns value in base64. You have to convert it to HEX format by yourself (of course if you want that). Example of how it can be achieved can be found for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784345/conversion-between-base64string-and-hexadecimal):

```
string HashInString = BitConverter.ToString(computedHashCode ).Replace("-", "");
```

Provided example is correct:

`M1UOF9zlCe+LwCfDNcWGPw==` in `Base64` is equal to `33550e17dce509ef8bc027c335c5863f` HEX. Use [Base64 to Hex Converter](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en) to check it!

Answer (score 0):

> Input: 213441dasses Output: M1UOF9zlCe+LwCfDNcWGPw== Expected output:
>   33550e17dce509ef8bc027c335c5863f

Your expected output is a hexadecimal string, while your actual output isn't. You're currently converting the hash into a 64-based string, which is obvisouly not what you want.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436358/870604) for how to return your expected hex string from the hash.

Comment: I don't get what the "str" in your link stands for ?

Comment: @Lasse It's the string you're hashing. The important part is what's after "To convert the hash to a hex string..."

Comment: I have now done as in your link, but it's still wrong. Expected output 33550e17dce509ef8bc027c335c5863f Output: C81414CA06C3AAA287AB6B2978A1DF38EEF308AF